# Modifying a previously echoed variable

Tags: php

There are two files that I am able to modify

**header.tpl** and **product.tpl**

I do not have access to any of the controller or model files

For SEO purposes I am trying to modifiy the following meta data while on a product page.

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
```

Currently `$description` does not have any output. However on my `product.tpl` I have a variable `<?php echo $heading_title ?>` which is essentially the text that I would like to have in the header `meta` data.

Is this even possible to achieve without accessing the model/controller or am I just wasting my time?

Comment: Is javascript an option?

Comment: I am not sure but are you able to do some thing like `$_SESSION['description'] = $heading_title;` on all tpl pages and  `<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $_SESSION['description']; ?>" />`

Comment: Search engines wont be able to read the data from what I understand if its placed via javascript. I am also using the same concept for facebooks `og:image` and it will not work with `js`

Comment: Not possible without controller. And for SEO you cannot change using js.

Comment: If the html is sequentially rendered (meaning top to bottom), then there is no way, except for maybe fiddling with output-buffering. Though doing this inisde the templates seems really out of place.

Comment: I assume that the variables $heading_title and $description are definited in the same controller and sent in the product.tpl, so they're accessible in all the file. I suggest you something like this: `<meta name="description" content="<?php echo empty($description) ? $heading_title : $description ; ?>" />`

Comment: Different controllers thats the main problem:(

Comment: @Yoshi How exactly would you go about it with output-buffering? Literally looking for any way possible haha

Comment: Do you explicitly include or require the header.tpl in your product.tpl file?

Comment: @DarraghEnright Header is explicitly called in the product.tpl via `<?php echo $header; ?>`

Comment: So the header is already a string when used inside the product tpl?

Comment: @Yoshi Yes I call the `$header` variable inside product.tpl

Comment: Well if `$header` is string, and the initial description is empty, you could simply to a `str_replace` on the variable to remove the empty meta-tag and place your own?

Comment: You mean `str_replace` the `$header` string on product.tpl and look for `<meta name="description" content="" />`?

Comment: Pretty much, yes ;)

Comment: INTERESTING! Let me try it out

Comment: I feel dirty but that worked feel free to make an answer and I can accept yours if you want @Yoshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The not so pretty but functional solution

```
<?php echo $header = preg_replace('/<meta name="description" content="" \/>/', '<meta name="description" content="' . $heading_title . '" \/>', $header); ?>
```

Comment: Just accept yours, mine wouldn't be much different anyway. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments: Once something has been sent to the browser (or any other output), it is impossible to change it server-side.

The best solution, if you are able to edit the contents of the header with `preg_replace()` etc, is to simply set the variable *before* including the header.
So that instead of something like this:

```
include "header.tpl";
$data = get_from_db ();
echo do_some_processing ($data);
include "footer.tpl";
```

You move all of the processing before you start to output anything to the browser, which completely eliminates the paradox of having to change something you've already sent. Which should leave you with a code looking something like this:

```
// Do all of the processing first.
$data = get_form_db ();
$output = do_some_processing ();

// Then, when all of the processing is done, output to browser.
include "header.tpl";
echo $output;
include "footer.tpl";
```

It also has the added benefit of making your PHP code *much* simpler to read, and thus easier to maintain in the long run. Even on this small code sample, you can see the difference a proper seperation of concerns does.